# EF reverse POCO generator Unit Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, poco

I am using [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator) which has a flag

```
AddUnitTestingDbContext = true; // Will add a FakeDbContext and FakeDbSet for easy unit testing
```

It creates **FakeDbContext** and **FakeDbSet** for unit testing, but inside **FakeDbContext** some of the methods are not implemented.

```
 public System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry Entry(object entity)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult> GetValidationErrors()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet Set(System.Type entityType)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

What would be the correct way to overwrite them or implement them so that I can use those calls in my unit tests.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would leave the fake context as a "one time" generation and customize it.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Move the context out. Then fill in the blanks from the original.

Comment: This file is auto generated I can't modify that code... It will get overwritten next time someone clicks save...

Comment: yes. but, you would have to move it somewhere else, and then when someone clicks save, delete the newly generated copy.

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out. You can write code in **EF.Reverse.POCO.ttinclude** file which will be regenerated. Open that file and locate function **Set()** then you can write something like this to get desired functionality. Hope this will be helpful to someone.

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : 
class
    {
<#
foreach (Table tbl in from t in tables.Where(t => !t.IsMapping && 
t.HasPrimaryKey).OrderBy(x => x.NameHumanCase) select t)
{
#>


        if(typeof(TEntity) == typeof(<#=tbl.NameHumanCaseWithSuffix #>))
        {
            return <#=Inflector.MakePlural(tbl.NameHumanCase) #> as 
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>;
        }

<# } #>

        throw new System.NotImplementedException("Doesn't have this table type!");
     }
```